# Hbase Standalone vs Pseudo distributed mode for nutch crawler

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, nutch

I'm running Nutch crawler for three smaller sites. Every day I crawl <500k URLs, on a single machine. Per customer wishes, there will not be a cluster of 2+ machines for hadoop cluster. Only one server instance.

I understand that neither Standalone and Pseudo distributed mode is recommended for production, but...

**Q1:** which of these modes is 'Lesser evil' - Nutch is written so it can be run on single machine. Which of these modes were intended for this scenario?

**Q2:** Currently we are running Hbase in Standalone mode and from time to time hbase just crashes without anything in logs. HMaster stops and cannot be restarted without fixing meta and repairing inconsistencies (Connection refused). Could such error be caused by the standalone mode?

**note 1:** We do not need hadoop data replication, because number of urls is small.

**note 2:** We do not need parallelism for hadoop jobs, because number of urls is small

Because of note 1,2 I think that plain File system should be enough and hdfs in unnecessary. Am I right?

Comment: Why not fix your existing setup? Have you tried monitoring your Hbase components in order to understand root cause behind your crashes and prevent them?

Comment: I look for the problem with existing setup. Q2 was meant to mean: Because Standalone mode is not meant for production environment, is it possible that we will encounter stability problems we would not experience when using distributed mode. Or in terms of stability, is standalone mode 'safe'?